# Disable Win+S Key on Windows 8.1?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1

How can the Windows + S keyboard shortcut be disabled on Windows 8.1?

I had Win+S mapped to take a screen capture in Windows 8 using Evernote. (not using Windows built-in PrintScr to capture the entire screen):
[image]

After the update, Win+S always brings up the Search panel:
[image]

A solution using RegEdit would be fine. I just need it disabled so that other capture programs, such as Evernote and Greenshot can use it (as before, pre-Win 8.1).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable preassigned Windows shortcuts with a registry Hack. Just start a new plaintext file with the content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DisabledHotkeys"=hex(2):53,00,00,00
```

and save it as something like `disableWinS.reg`. Run the created reg file by double-clicking and confirm the prompt to add the key to your registry. Then restart your machine and Win+S is happy to be assigned by Evernote!

PS: `53,00,00,00` is just hex code for S. If other keys are required, just check a [ASCII Code chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart.svg)

(source: http://forum.voidtools.com/viewtopic.php?p=8942#p8942)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for disabling Win-Z :(

Comment: I'm not sure what Win-Z is binded to. It seems "free" on my Win 8.1 machine with German keyboard layout/language settings. What happens when you press it?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press it, but other programs (ArsClip and Jing in particular. I don't use Evernote or Greensnap) that allow me to set hotkeys, don't come up if I have assigned Win-Z.

Comment: Aha. [This list from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8) says Win-Z is reserved for "Show the commands available in the app" -- presumably, on Metro apps.

Comment: This works for Windows 10 also ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Win+S used to give you OneNote screen capture; now it goes to Win8.1 search. However Win+Shift+S still goes to onenote.

Comment: Good point. That works for OneNote 2013, but not for OneNote 2010. Also, really looking for a non-OneNote solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) you can reclaim keys that even the `DisabledHotkeys` registry setting won't restore.  For example, this AutoHotKey script will remap Win-Z to Shift-Ctrl-Z. Configure your program to respond to Shift-Ctrl-Z and it won't know the difference.

```
#Z::Send,^+Z
```

Comment: Oh, just noticed @jaychris also mentioned AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.1, Win + PrtScrn is the key for screen capture.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/take-screen-capture-print-screen#take-screen-capture-print-screen=windows-8

I can think of a couple of ways to keep Win + S to be quiet.

1. May not be for everyone. Autohotkey can be used to map any key to anything. Win + S can be mapped to do nothing. I am not elaborating since you might not be interested in this.
2. A dummy .bat file can be created and Win + S can be used as the shortcut key. Some instructions can be found here. http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4999-shortcuts-assign-keyboard-shortcut-windows-8-a.html. Basically create a donothing.bat in the desktop and assign Win + S as its shortcut key.

Comment: Win+PrintScreen is the key for screen capture in windows 8 too

Comment: Good point, PrintScr can be used to capture the _entire_ screen. Is there a way to capture only the selected region?

Comment: @Rubistro I like the built-in "Snipping Tool" for that, but have also been known to run Greenshot which maps itself to just printscrn, and is free.

Answer (score -1):

You must login to OneNote account, then open OneNote application, enable copy to the clipboard option.
Now you can use **WIN + SHIFT + S**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).